# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am using Hadoop 1.0.3 and HBase 0.94.22. I am trying to run a mapper program to read values from a Hbase table and output them to a file. I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

The code is as below

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.FirstKeyOnlyFilter;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


    public class Test {

    static class TestMapper extends TableMapper<Text, IntWritable> {
        private static final IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);

        public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result value, Context context) throws    IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            ImmutableBytesWritable userkey = new ImmutableBytesWritable(row.get(), 0 , Bytes.SIZEOF_INT);
            String key =Bytes.toString(userkey.get());
            context.write(new Text(key), one);

        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HBaseConfiguration conf = new HBaseConfiguration();
        Job job = new Job(conf, "hbase_freqcounter");
        job.setJarByClass(Test.class);
        Scan scan = new Scan();

        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        String columns = "data";
        scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes(columns));
        scan.setFilter(new FirstKeyOnlyFilter());
        TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob("test",scan, TestMapper.class, Text.class, IntWritable.class, job);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);

    }

}
```

I get the above code exported to a jar file and on the command line I use the below command to run the above code.

hadoop jar /home/testdb.jar test

where test is the folder to which the mapper results should be written.

I have checked a few other links like [Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150604/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-zookeeper-keeperexceptio) where it has been suggested to include the zookeeper file in the classpath, but while creating the project in eclipse I have already included zookeeper file from the lib directory of hbase. The file I have included is zookeeper-3.4.5.jar. Ans also visited this link too [HBase - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425219/hbase-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-in-java) , but I am using a mapper class to get the values from the hbase table not any client API. I know I am making a mistake somewhere, guys could you please help me out ??

I have noted another strange thing, when I remove all of the code in the main function except the first line " HBaseConfiguration conf = new HBaseConfiguration();", then export the code to a jar file and try to compile the jar file as hadoop jar test.jar I still get the same error. It seems either I am defining the conf variable incorrectly or there is some issue with my environment.

Answer (score 8):

I got the fix to the problem, I had not added the hbase classpath in the hadoop-env.sh file. Below is the one I added to make the job work.

```
$ export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HBASE_HOME/hbase-0.94.22.jar:\
    $HBASE_HOME/hbase-0.94.22-test.jar:\
    $HBASE_HOME/conf:\
    ${HBASE_HOME}/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar:\
    ${HBASE_HOME}/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar:\
    ${HBASE_HOME}/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried editing the `hadoop-env.sh` file, but the changes mentioned here didn't work for me.

What worked is this:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$HBASE_HOME/lib/*"
```

I just added that at the end of my `hadoop-env.sh`.
Do not forget to set your `HBASE_HOME` variable.
You can also replace the `$HBASE_HOME` with the actual path of your hbase installation.

Answer (score 2):

In case there is someone who has different paths/configuration. Here is what I added to `hadoop-env.sh` in order to make it work:

```
$ export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="$HBASE_HOME/lib/hbase-client-0.98.11-hadoop2.jar:\
    $HBASE_HOME/lib/hbase-common-0.98.11-hadoop2.jar:\
    $HBASE_HOME/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:\
    $HBASE_HOME/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar:\
    $HBASE_HOME/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:\
    $HBASE_HOME/lib/hbase-protocol-0.98.11-hadoop2.jar"
```

**NOTE:** if you haven't set the `$HBASE_HOME` you have 2 choices.
 - By `export HBASE_HOME=[your hbase installation path]`
 - Or just replace the `$HBASE_HOME` with your hbase full path

Answer (score 0):

add

```
set HBASE_CLASSPATH=%HBASE_HOME%\lib\client-facing-thirdparty\*
```

hbase-env.cmd or hbase-env.sh

Answer (score -1):

```
HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true \
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$($HBASE_HOME/bin/hbase mapredcp) \
hadoop jar  /home/testdb.jar test
```

Answer (score -1):

here CreateTable is my java class file

use this command

`java -cp .:/home/hadoop/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/hbase-0.94.8.jar:/home/hadoop/hbase/hbase-0.94.8/lib/*  CreateTable`