# how to fix java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration

Tags: maven, dependencies, hbase

I am using hadoop and hbase. the hbase version is 1.1.1.2.3. I try to use maven to  compile, run the project. But it has the org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration not find problem. 
Here is my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.20.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.6</version>
            </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0a</version>
            </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
            </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>0.23.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-protocol</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
    <version>0.94.27</version>
  </dependency>
      <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
                <artifactId>hbase-server</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
                <artifactId>hbase-testing-util</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

dependencies are as above, I really do not know what to add more. Could anyone help? with many thanks. I know there are many problems similar but none of them is using the newest version base and I tried there solution, does not work. thanks
Furthermore, I tried to add the dependency: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase/1.1.1
but get error:  *`Failed to execute goal on project hbaseTable: Could not resolve dependencies for project apache.hbase:hbaseTable:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:1.1.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced`*

Comment: Error showing like jar is missing check whether the jar has loaded in your project check this link also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364057/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-hadoop-hba

Comment: @Soorapadman Yes, I saw that post before, but its hbase version is 0. 9.4  which we could find the corresponding jar file. Mine I could not find the apache.hadoop.hbase jar with version 1.1.1

Comment: Maybe, your corporate maven repo is blocking that dependency. Make sure that org.apache.hbase is not blocked.