# Exception when using the saveToPhoenix method to load/save a RDD on Hbase

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-phoenix

I would like to use the apache-phoenix framework.
The problem is that I keep having an exception telling me that the class HBaseConfiguration can't be found.
Here is the code I want to use:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.phoenix.spark._

// Load INPUT_TABLE
object MainTest2 extends App {
  val sc = new SparkContext("local", "phoenix-test")
  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
  val df = sqlContext.load("org.apache.phoenix.spark", Map("table" -> "INPUT_TABLE",
    "zkUrl" -> "localhost:3888"))
}
```

Here is the SBT I'm using :

```
name := "spark-to-hbase"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-mapreduce-client-core" % "2.3.0",
  "org.apache.phoenix" % "phoenix-core" % "4.11.0-HBase-1.3",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.phoenix" % "phoenix-spark" % "4.11.0-HBase-1.3"
)
```

And here is the exception :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration    at
>   org.apache.phoenix.query.ConfigurationFactory$ConfigurationFactoryImpl$1.call(ConfigurationFactory.java:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.query.ConfigurationFactory$ConfigurationFactoryImpl$1.call(ConfigurationFactory.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:76)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.callWithoutPropagation(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:91)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.query.ConfigurationFactory$ConfigurationFactoryImpl.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.initializeConnectionCache(PhoenixDriver.java:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.(PhoenixDriver.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.(PhoenixDriver.java:69)
>     at org.apache.phoenix.spark.PhoenixRDD.(PhoenixRDD.scala:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.phoenix.spark.PhoenixRelation.schema(PhoenixRelation.scala:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation.(LogicalRelation.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.baseRelationToDataFrame(SparkSession.scala:389)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.load(SQLContext.scala:965)   at
>   MainTest2$.delayedEndpoint$MainTest2$1(MainTest2.scala:9)     at
>   MainTest2$delayedInit$body.apply(MainTest2.scala:6)   at
>   scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)    at
>   scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
>     at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)    at
>   scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)     at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)   at
>   scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
>     at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)   at
>   MainTest2$.main(MainTest2.scala:6)    at MainTest2.main(MainTest2.scala)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 26 more

I've already tried to change the HADOOP_CLASSPATH in hadoop-env.sh like it is said in this previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364057/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-hadoop-hba).

What can I do to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. As the exception says, my compiler isn't able to find the class HBaseConfiguration. HBaseConfiguration is used inside org.apache.hadoop.hbase library and so is needed to compile. I noticed that the HBaseConfiguration class wasn't present in the org.apache.hadoop library as I thought. For the hbase 1.3.1 version installed on my PC computer, I managed to find this class in the hbase-common-1.3.1 jar located in my HBASE_HOME/lib folder.

Then I include this dependency in my built.SBT :

"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.3.1"

And the Exception was gone.